# string Format - how to change negative sign position

Tags: c#, string, sign

I have a `string.Format` like this :

```
string Test = string.Format("{0:#,0}", NegativeNumber);
```

how can I change the negative sign position (Direction -> left or right)?

Comment: Can you post examples for the required output for different inputs?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest route might be to just have a different format for negative numbers

```
string Test = string.Format("{0:#,0;#,0-}", NegativeNumber);
```

Results:

```
PS C:\> '{0:#,0;#,0-}' -f -17.2

17-

PS C:\> '{0:#,0;#,0-}' -f 17.2

17
```

[Custom Numeric Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx)

> The semicolon `(;)` is a conditional format specifier that applies different formatting to a number depending on whether its value is positive, negative, or zero. To produce this behavior, a custom format string can contain up to three sections separated by semicolons. These sections are described in the following table.

Comment: Can we just specify the position of minus sign, and respect the culture's formatting?

Answer (score 0):

Would this work:

```
String.Format("{0:0.00;0.00-;zero}", -123.4567);
```