# Scientific notation sign

Tags: c#, numbers

I'm writing numbers in a file and they should be looking like this:

```
  5.22226E+00 -2.31833E-01 -9.28221E-01  5.23851E+00 -2.33228E-01 -9.33804E-01
  5.25481E+00 -2.34622E-01 -9.39387E-01  5.27116E+00 -2.36016E-01 -9.44969E-01
  5.28756E+00  3.65029E-01  9.14477E-01  5.30401E+00  3.66841E-01  9.19016E-01
  5.32051E+00  3.68653E-01  9.23556E-01  5.33707E+00  3.70464E-01  9.28095E-01
  5.35367E+00  3.72276E-01  9.32634E-01  5.37033E+00  3.74088E-01  9.37174E-01
```

Instead they are:

```
  5.22226E+00 -2.31833E-01 -9.28221E-01  5.23851E+00 -2.33228E-01 -9.33804E-01
  5.25481E+00 -2.34622E-01 -9.39387E-01  5.27116E+00 -2.36016E-01 -9.44969E-01
  5.28756E+00 3.65029E-01 9.14477E-01  5.30401E+00 3.66841E-01 9.19016E-01
  5.32051E+00 3.68653E-01 9.23556E-01  5.33707E+00 3.70464E-01 9.28095E-01
  5.35367E+00 3.72276E-01 9.32634E-01  5.37033E+00 3.74088E-01 9.37174E-01
```

The difference is that I'm not inserting a space when the sign is "+". How could I do that?

The code I use is

```
myNumber.ToString("0.00000E+00", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3287372/string-format-how-to-change-negative-sign-position), the semicolon sets the formatting according to positive numbers, then negative.

```
myNumber.ToString(" 0.00000E+00;-0.00000E+00", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

You can also force a `+` to appear if you want, or change the way the `-` sign is displayed.

Answer (score 3):

`PadLeft` should do the trick nicely:

```
myNumber.ToString("0.00000E+00", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).PadLeft(12);
```

Comment: Super! that thing will save me hours. Actually to write this file I need to insert a lot of spaces if the number or string are not filling the designed space. I was thinking to do that with conditionals..

Comment: @Sturm Sorry, not sure what you're talking about in the second part. But no problem!

Comment: This is very helpful indeed, and solves this problem and more. But I think that @Pierre-Luc Pineault provides the specific answer for the question.

Answer (score 3):

The best approach would be to use [conditional formatting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx#SectionSeparator):

```
myNumber.ToString(" 0.00000E+00;-0.00000E+00", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

An alternative (more verbose) approach:

```
string s = myNumber.ToString("0.00000E+00", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
if (myNumber >= 0)
    s = " " + s;
```

Comment: I prefer it over the `PadLeft(12)` approach since it's less susceptible to breaking should the format string be changed.

Comment: If the format string is changed the padding is bound to be changed **anyways**, so that's not really a factor.

Comment: Of course, unless the developer making the change miscounts the new required number of spaces.